# Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken'

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I use twitter4j library to make somethings with twitter. But i have a problem about AccesToken class. I checked my libraries, there is only one AccesToken class and it is in twitter4j.http 
There are no other AccesToken class. 
My code was working about 10 hours ago, but now it doesn't work. I am about to go mad :/

Here is my log trace:

```
04-24 15:53:32.767: E/dalvikvm(305): Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.twitterresim.TwitterOnay.isAuthenticated
04-24 15:53:32.767: W/dalvikvm(305): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Ltwitter4j/http/AccessToken;) in Lcom/twitterresim/TwitterOnay;
04-24 15:53:32.767: D/dalvikvm(305): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
04-24 15:53:32.767: D/dalvikvm(305): Making a copy of Lcom/twitterresim/TwitterOnay;.isAuthenticated code (124 bytes)
04-24 15:53:32.767: E/dalvikvm(305): Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.twitterresim.TwitterOnay.sendTweet
04-24 15:53:32.767: W/dalvikvm(305): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Ltwitter4j/http/AccessToken;) in Lcom/twitterresim/TwitterOnay;
04-24 15:53:32.767: D/dalvikvm(305): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
04-24 15:53:32.767: D/dalvikvm(305): Making a copy of Lcom/twitterresim/TwitterOnay;.sendTweet code (104 bytes)
04-24 15:53:32.767: D/AndroidRuntime(305): Shutting down VM
04-24 15:53:32.767: W/dalvikvm(305): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-24 15:53:32.776: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.twitterresim.TwitterOnay.isAuthenticated(TwitterOnay.java:18)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.twitterresim.TwitterPost.TwitterUpdate(TwitterPost.java:38)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.twitterresim.TwitterResimActivity$1.onClick(TwitterResimActivity.java:23)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-24 15:53:32.786: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What happened in those ten hours? did you play with the project configuration? with the file system?

Comment: no, i did not make any changes. just tried some other thing in my code, then i undo changes. i dont make any changes about libraries.

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: How are you building your project? Can you include your build script?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet i've tried already :(

Comment: @Gren i could not understand your question. I am using Eclipse and i run it via Run button if you ask this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try renaming the "lib" folder name to "libs". That solved the issue for me, check here:
https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample/issues/2