# Accesstoken error in Twitter api Integration

Tags: android, twitter

I'm new to android development and I am trying to integrate twitter api, but I'm getting an error with this line:

```
AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);//error
```

My error is:

> Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken'`, referenced from method com.android.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated""

I have already added 4 libraries in the libs folder.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question][1] (with answer).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301789/could-not-find-class-twitter4j-http-accesstoken